# How to make sure a zero is always at the end

Tags: c#, .net

I need to make sure that a double always ends with 0

```
6 = 6.0  
5.9876577878 = 5.98765778780
```

I tried the format but did not bring the expected result.

How can this be done?

Comment: what format string did you try?

Comment: You don't have formatting problem, but ROUNDING and FORMATTING problem.  Try to explain better what do you really need.

Comment: string.format("0.00", double);  doub.Tostring("0.00")

Comment: Dare I ask why you have this requirement?

Comment: well, the customer wants it so :)

Comment: Are you sure? Do you know why they want this?

Comment: Since the customer is clueless: value.ToString("0.00") + "0"

Comment: Adding a zero to the end indicates a false level of precision.  That's a pretty poor requirement.

Comment: As Kirk said - thats a poor requirement - what if the number was PI? You would turn a number which is as correct as it can be for the given precision to a number which is actually wrong

Comment: This question is liable to irreparably maim the minds of thousands of young programmers.  It really should not be preserved.

Comment: I'm here chasing the same requirement. I don't know about the OP, but my problem resulted from the different precision levels used for DateTime.Ticks in C# and  PostGres.  Values before and after storage didn't match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if the String.Format method allows you to do this. Here's something you can do though:

```
public static class DoubleUtils {
    public static String EnsureEndsWithZero(this double value) {
        String str = value.ToString();
        if(!str.EndsWith("0")) {
            if(str.Contains(".")) {
                str += "0";
            } else {
                str += ".0";
            }
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
double val = 10.1;
Console.WriteLine(val.EnsureEndsWithZero());
```

Comment: For completness you could make it possible to pass CultureInfo (or IFormatProvider) and check CultureFormat.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator instead of just using ".", but definately +1.

Comment: At least append the letter o instead of a zero so it is visible to somebody that needs to know.

Comment: What happens when your number looks like `1.234e+15`? You get `1.234e+150`!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're extremely liberal about how many zeros are at the end of the number (i.e. 1 **OR MORE** zeros is okay), then I think you'd have to check the resulting string to see if there's a zero after the decimal point, and add one or both if they aren't there.